# Regular expression for a huge data block

Tags: java, regex

I've had a task to process big rtf-files, >500Мb. I needed to find and extract parts from these big files.

It was a working prototype, written on Java, for demonstration purposes.

I created a regular expression, which worked for smaller rtf files (~10Мb), and tried to apply this expression for huge files.

And I get "Stack overflow" error upon execution of this regexp.

As far as I understand regular expressions have recursive nature, and it is the reason of the exception I get. On the smaller files that regexp worked well and fast.

Do I understand the reason correctly?

Comment: We need to see your regex with some sample data to understand it better.

Comment: Are you using a language or a text editor? FWIW, if text editor, EditPad Pro by regex guru Jan Goyvaerts has awesome regex and handles files in the gigabytes.

Comment: @anubhava Unfortunately now I do not have access to source code, sorry.

Comment: @zx81 I used java to make a working prototype for demonstration purposes. And java worked well on small files, but threw stackoverflow on huge files.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov _Potentially_ (Please don't take this personally), your regex was inefficient and misses places where it can use atomic groups. PCRE does a good job at optimizing their engine.

Comment: @Unihedron good point, thank you

Comment: @Unihedron: A regex can't be inefficient. It can be compiled to work in linear time... You can here see how a programming language normally handles a regex: http://ivanzuzak.info/noam/webapps/fsm_simulator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No: regular expressions have no recursive nature. Any decent language simply converts such expression into a finite state machine. This means it requires the same amount of memory (and as a consequence stack size as well) to filter a file of 10 MiB or of 500 MiB. Furthermore it scales linearly in time: one expect it takes 50 times more time to filter a file of 500 MiB than one of 10 MiB.

What are you using a regex evaluator? For `grep`/`sed` smaller or larger files are not an issue.

Comment: I used regex in my java code, to make fast-n-dirty working prototype for demonstration purposes.

Comment: But then can you show us the regex and are you sure it has anything to do with the regex anyhow. Furthermore of course the regex must be syntactically correct.

Comment: it was correct and worked on smaller files perfectly. But failed on huge files.

Comment: Why can't you show us the regex and the stacktrace? It is very hard to argue without any data...

Comment: It was long time ago, and I do not have access to the source code now. Just wanted to clarify for myself. Was my assumption correct or not. Thank you :)

Comment: As an ANTLR fan I'm aware of the state machines your talking about, but Java's regex engine definitely has some recursion going on because running [this test](https://gist.github.com/Groostav/44a31c904c3bf8c45085) against a huge file generates a stack overflow error.